# ul - li. New equal row(li), below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any suggestions?

1. I would like a new li to be created underneath the same li when using the button "new". In my example the .append creates the new li at the bottom.
2. The buttons (new, sub, up, down and x) should appear in the new li, how?

Appologize for if this questions requires a big and quite substantial response and I don´t expect anyone to give it. Then if these list attributes require some other type of coding, .net and other, Im happy to be enlightened...

Thanks
David

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="text-decoration:none">

  <li>..............
    <button id="btn2">New</button>
    <button id="btn3">Sub</button>
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
    <button>X</button>
  </li>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn2").click(function() {
        $("ul").append("<li>..............</li>");
      });
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#btn3").click(function() {
        $("ul").append("<ul><li>..............</li>");
      });
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    $('.up').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().insertBefore($(this).parent().prev());
    });

    $('.down').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().insertAfter($(this).parent().next());
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("<li>").remove();
    });
  </script>

</ul>
```

Comment: Its creating new `li` underneath the same `li` but since your already present `li` is having buttons inside it, you are not able to move buttons, when new `li` is created..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending to the `ul`, insert it after the current `li` element.

Also you can clone and add the buttons, and use event delegation to handle click in the new buttons

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul").on('click', '.btn2', function() {
    $("<li/>", {
      text: '..............'
    }).append($(this).parent().children('button').clone()).insertAfter(this.parentNode);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn3").click(function() {
    $("ul").append("<ul><li>..............</li>");
  });
});

$('ul').on('click', '.up', function() {
  $(this).parent().insertBefore($(this).parent().prev());
});

$('ul').on('click', '.down', function() {
  $(this).parent().insertAfter($(this).parent().next());
});

$('ul').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="text-decoration:none">

  <li>..............
    <button class="btn2">New</button>
    <button class="btn3">Sub</button>
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </li>



</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Arun,  your codes were amazing and really helpfull. One question, if I would want add the "Sub" button, how would you do that? Sub: Adding a subgroup (a new li underneath)

Answer (score 0):

Hi now  used to class as like this

i have used to  **[.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)** **[.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**  and **[.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $(document).on('click','.btn2',function() {
        var thisLi = $(this).closest('li').clone();
        $(thisLi).prependTo('ul');
      });
  
  
  $(document).on('click','.remove',function() {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
      });

  
  
 // $('.up').click(function() {
//      $(this).parent().insertBefore($(this).parent().prev());
  //  });

  
  //  $('.down').click(function() {
  //    $(this).parent().insertAfter($(this).parent().next());
 //   });

  
  //  $("button").click(function() {
 //     $("<li>").remove();
 //   });
 // 
  
  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="text-decoration:none">

  <li>..............
    <button class="btn2">New</button>
    <button class="btn3">Sub</button>
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </li>



</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Rohit, you gave a great and easy code to use. How could I add a sub: Sub li underneath, like a tree model?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){ 
  $(document).on('click', '.new', newItem);
  $(document).on('click', '.sub', subItem);
  $(document).on('click', '.remove', removeItem);
  $(document).on('click', '.up', moveUpItem);
  $(document).on('click', '.down', moveDownItem);
});

function newItem(){
  var $btn  = $(this),
      $li   = $btn.closest('li').clone(),
      $ul   = $btn.closest('ul'),
      count = $ul.find('li').length + 1;

  $li.find('span').text(count);
  $li.find('ul').remove();

  $ul.append($li);
}

function subItem(){
  var $btn     = $(this),
      $li      = $btn.closest('li'),
      $liClone = $btn.closest('li').clone(),
      hasSubs  = $li.find('ul').length > 0,
      $ul      = hasSubs ? $li.find('ul') : $('<ul>');

  var countSubs = $ul.find('li').length + 1;
  $liClone.addClass('sub-item');
  $liClone.find('span').text(countSubs);
  $liClone.find('ul').remove();

  $ul.append($liClone);

  if(!hasSubs)
    $li.append($ul);
}

function removeItem(){
  var $li     = $(this).closest('li'),
      liCount = $li.closest('ul').find('li').length;

  if(liCount > 1 || $li.hasClass('sub-item'))
    $li.remove();
  else
    alert('este é o ultimo.');
}

function moveUpItem () {
  var $li = $(this).closest('li'),
      $ul = $li.closest('ul'),
      index = $li.index() + 1;

  if(index > 1){
    var $temp = $li.detach();
    $ul.find('li:nth-child('+(index - 1)+')').before($temp);
  }
}

function moveDownItem () {
  var $li = $(this).closest('li'),
      $ul = $li.closest('ul'),
      count = $ul.find('li').length,
      index = $li.index() + 1;

  if(index < count){
    var $temp = $li.detach();
    $ul.find('li:nth-child('+(index)+')').after($temp);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
   <span>1</span>
    <button class="new">New</button>
    <button class="sub">Sub</button>
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```